# How to distinguish between priors and likelihood in PyMC3

Tags: pymc3

In PyMC3 examples, priors and likelihood are defined inside `with` statement, but they are not explicitly defined if they are priors or likelihood. How do I define them?

In following example code, `alpha` and `beta` are priors and `y_obs` is likelihood(As PyMC3 examples states).

My question is: How PyMC3 internal code finds out if distribution is of prior or likelihood? There should be some explicit parameter to tell PyMC3 internals about type of distribution (prior/likelihood).

I know `y_obs` is likelihood, but I could define more `y_obs1` `y_obs2`. How PyMC3 is going to identify which one is likelihood and which one is prior.

```py
from pymc3 import Model, Normal, HalfNormal

regression_model = Model()  
with regression_model:  

    alpha = Normal('alpha', mu=0, sd=10)
    beta = Normal('beta', mu=0, sd=10, shape=2)

    sigma = HalfNormal('sigma', sd=1)

    mu = alpha + beta[0] * X[:,0] + beta[1] * X[:,1]

    y_obs = Normal('y_obs', mu=mu, sd=sigma, observed=y)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing an `observed` argument makes it a likelihood term (in your example, `P[y|mu, sigma]`).  The other `RandomVariable` variables (`alpha`, `beta`, and `sigma`), lacking an `observed` argument, are sampled as priors.